PSTricks differences with engines -- pdflatex vs. xelatex
I have an MWE:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3,-1.4)(4,1.4)
\psbrace[braceWidth=0.5pt,braceWidthInner=8pt,rot=90,ref=lc,nodesepB=8pt](-2,-0.35)(1,-0.35){$A$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}

that when processed with
latex file.tex
dvips -o file.ps file.dvi
ps2pdf file.ps

produces what is expected to be the correct picture -- with the label on the horizontal

and when processed with
xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -i dvipdfmx-unsafe.cfg -q -E" file.tex

it rotates the label and places it with a vertical alignement.

Can anyone shed some light on what is going on here?

GhostScript does a AutoRotatePage. However, use lualatex instead of xelatex:
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{pspicture}(-3,-1.4)(4,1.4)
        \psbrace[braceWidth=0.5pt,braceWidthInner=8pt,rot=90,ref=lc,nodesepB=8pt](-2,-0.35)(1,-0.35){$A$}
    \end{pspicture}
    
\end{document}

